# Does this prove continuity?

Tags: real-analysis, continuity

Suppose I have a function $f\colon X\times Y\to Z$ and suppose on the product space $X\times Y$ I have a metric $d$ which is a sum of two metrics, say

$$
d((x,y),(x',y'))=d_1(x,x')+d_2(y,y').
$$

On $Z$, I have metric $d_Z$.

Now, if I want to show that $f$ is continuous, I have to show that for each $\varepsilon >0$ there exists some $\delta>0$ such that
$$
d((x,x'),y,y'))\leq\delta\implies d_Z(f(x,y),f(x',y'))\leq\varepsilon.
$$

Now, my question is if the following is appropriate or nonsens:
Does the following show continuity of $f$?

For each $\varepsilon >0$, if I set $y=y'$, i.e. $d_2(y,y')=0$, I can find a $\delta>0$ such that the implication above holds.

For me this is strange since I always have to have $d_2(y,y')=0$. I do not know if this really proves continuity then.

Answer (score 1):

1. In order to be able to say that $f$ is continuous at $(x_0,y_0)$ you should show that for any $(x,y)$ satisfying $d((x_0,y_0),(x,y)) \leq \delta $ the values of $f$ should be close i.e. $d_z(f(x,y), f(x_0,y_0)) \leq \epsilon $. In that sense, if you pick $y=y_0$ then you are not working with arbitrary points anymore.
2. Consider the following: $X,Y= \mathbb{R}$ with the standard metric. Then $Z= \mathbb{R}^2$ with [taxicab metric](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taxicab_geometry). Now consider $f(x,y) = 1 $ if $y \in \mathbb{Q}$ and $f(x,y)= 0$ otherwise. In this case, $f$ is not continuous at any point but continuous on horizontal lines, i.e. when $y=y_0$ fixed.

Answer (score 1):

No, what you did does **NOT** prove continuity, so you're right in feeling doubtful about this. The reason for why it's wrong can be clearly seen if you set up the actual $\varepsilon$-$\delta$ definition of continuity:

> $f:A\to B$ is *continuous* at a point $a_0$ if for any $\varepsilon>0$ there exists $\delta>0$ such that **for any** $a\in A$ we have: $d(a,a_0)<\delta \implies d(f(a),f(a_0))<\varepsilon$.

Applied to the situation in your question, this becomes:

> $f:X\times Y\to Z$ is *continuous* at a point $(x,y)$ if for any $\varepsilon>0$ there exists $\delta>0$ such that **for any** $(x',y')\in X\times Y$ we have: $d((x,y),(x',y'))<\delta \implies d_Z(f(x,y),f(x',y'))<\varepsilon$.

In this definition, finding an appropriate $\delta$ comes **before** considering points $(x',y')$, and moreover the condition must hold for **all** such points — meaning you **can't** select it in some special convenient way.

Your mistake was that you chose some special points $(x',y')$ (which you can't do) and you chose them before defining $\delta$ (which you can't do either, as $\delta$ must be defined first). What you did would effectively demonstrate continuity of $f$ as a function of a single variable $x$ only while holding $y$ constant. But that's not the same as proving the (joint) continuity of $f$.

And one more comment. The definition that you stated in your post is in fact the definition of a stronger property of **uniform continuity**:

> $f:X\times Y\to Z$ is *uniformly continuous* if for any $\varepsilon>0$ there exists $\delta>0$ such that **for any** $(x,y),(x',y')\in X\times Y$ we have: $d((x,y),(x',y'))<\delta \implies d_Z(f(x,y),f(x',y'))<\varepsilon$.

Comment: Very nicely explained.

Comment: @PeterSzilas: Thank you!